# M2 remove forward slash from footer link

Tags: magento-2.1, footer-links

I am using the following code in default.xml to edit the privacy policy URL however it is adding a trailing forward slash.

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">            
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="privacy-policy-link" after="contact-us-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Privacy and Cookie Policy</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">privacy-policy.html</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms" name="search-term-popular-link" after="sales-guest-form-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Search Terms</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">search/term/popular</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="contact/contact/enabled" name="contact-us-link" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
         <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Guest\Link" name="sales-guest-form-link" after="catalog-search-advanced-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Orders and Returns</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/guest/form</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="catalog-search-advanced-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Advanced Search</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">catalogsearch/advanced</argument>
                <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="data-action" xsi:type="string">advanced-search</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

On my website my privacy policy URL is privacy-policy.html/ - how can I change this to privacy-policy.html ?